# Value is not inserted at datatable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I've been inserting a 64bit string to a datatable. But when I tried to do so, it wasn't inserted at the end of the method. Here's my code regarding the adding of row.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DataDump", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Link", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(new Object[]{
    "81jhadasdjahdkahd/d1231231...", //64 bit string
    "key"
});
```

Is there any limit to what a datatable can hold? or what so?

This is the picture after the break

https://s17.postimg.org/4ahn7sxwv/datatable_c.png

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by a "64 bit string"? And how are you observing that the row isn't being added?

Comment: what's the exact error

Comment: Its a converted string for an image I've been trying to save, but I want it to put it in a holder first. That's why I used a datatable. 
I put a break point at the end of the adding of the row and there's no value. I have edited my post and posted the link for the image of break

Comment: ur code is working fine how r u checking if row is inserted or not ?

Comment: So,how long in characters is the string you try to add to the datacolumn?

Comment: Have you tried `DataTable.AcceptChanges();`

Comment: take ur break point one line below may be a temp variable

Comment: as ur break point seems not to let the function complete

Comment: @Pikoh it was 45492 characters.

Comment: @Usman as you can see to the image above, the other value for the column was added.

Comment: Where is that "FA6H5..." on the Screenshot coming from? It does not represent that code snippet you've posted.

Comment: I've just tried your code with a string of the same size and it works fine. To check if it is added, put a breakpoint after and in the inspection window put this: `dt.Rows[0]["DataDump"]`

Comment: What exactly have you added? You are not showing the real code.

Comment: This is my sample code,working just fine: `string s = new string('p', 45492);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DataDump", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Link", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new Object[]{
    s, 
    "key"
});`

Comment: this is what I am talking about, just ur code with some console write line command:
http://pho.to/ANrUd